# What's the order of events for nested While loops in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm teaching myself Python and I'm trying to make a basic game using RPG mechanics I'm familiar with.  My core mechanic looks like this:

```
while not GameOver():                    #checking for one side or the other to be all KO'd
    turnbegin()                          #resetting # of moves per player, etc
    while not TurnDone():                #checking to see if everyone's out of moves
        for ch in activechars:           #going through the players who still have moves
            if ch not in defeatedchars:  #ignoring the KO'd players
                attack(ch,target(ch))    #EVERYONE PUNCH EVERYONE (keeping it simple)
            else:
                pass
```

My problem is that this loop is still trying to run the target(ch) function after it should've hit GameOver().  The counters are down (everyone's KO'd) and the GameOver function seems to be working correctly; I checked.  But GameOver returns True and then...it just rolls on to attack() and kicks back an error that it doesn't have anyone to target instead of just stopping because it's over.  I tried creating a gameover=GameOver() variable and saying "while not gameover" instead, but then it just got stuck in turnbegin() after it said turn 2 began.

Thank you for reading this!  I'm very new to this and very thankful for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"while not GameOver()" is only evaluated when it finishes running and needs to enter another loop.

Since TurnDone() is still true, it doesn't exit the loop and GameOver() is not re-evaluated.

When GameOver() gets updated to True, then TurnDone() should become True as well to prevent it from entering another loop.

Comment: Thank you!  I just plain misunderstood how the loop was working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to update **activechars** list after **attack()**?
Also, if you have no logic after **attack()** inside for loop you can replace

```
else:
    pass
```

with nothing, get ride of that else it's irrelevant. Keep the code clean.

And you should use pep-8 (activechars must be active_chars, etc)

Comment: Thank you!  I actually thought I had to have an ELSE for every IF; I'll go clear a few lines out now.

I'm still working on the naming conventions but I'll update that soon.  Thank you for your comment!

Comment: You're welcome! You also have the keyword "continue" but in this case is better to just leave empty

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're storing activechars and defeatedchars in lists, maybe you could do something like this:

```
# This boolean will be False if there are no more undefeated active chars.
have_active_undefeated_chars = True

while not GameOver() and have_active_undefeated_chars:
    turnbegin()
    while not TurnDone():

        activechars_not_defeated = list(set(activechars) - set(defeatedchars))
        if len(activechars_not_defeated) == 0:
            have_active_undefeated_chars = False
            break

        for ch in activechars_not_defeated:
            attack(ch,target(ch))
```

activechars_not_defeated gets the elements in activechars that are not in defeatedchars, and the boolean have_active_undefeated_chars tells you if there are still active chars that are undefeated. The break statement will break you out of both while loops while have_active_undefeated_chars ensures that the loop won't run again.

You can also use the activechars_not_defeated list for the for loop.

Of course, I'm not familiar with your whole code, so I don't know if this will work in context. But hopefully, this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I do have them in lists; I actually have a third list that I reload activechars from during turnbegin, and then pop them when they run out of moves.  (I wanted to have multiple moves per unit, with distinct movement speeds, in orders determined by unit stat.)

It seems like I could just add if GameOver(): break after while not TurnDone()?  That's what I tried and it seemed to work.  Either way, thank you for your thoughts here!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution that works!